# Gathering nonconsecutive 1's by a Turing machine

Tags: computability, turing-machines

S. Barry Cooper comments his [output convention for $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ Turing machines](http://books.google.com/books?id=SJvt8ELnMakC&pg=PA37) like this:

> Outputting $n$ as $n$ possibly nonconsecutive $1$'s is very natural.
>   [...] We can achieve [gathering them together consecutively] with
>   a suitable "cleaning up" program.

If I [understand correctly](https://mathoverflow.net/a/179465/2672) this suitable "cleaning up" program cannot be a Turing machine.

What then does Cooper mean in this context?

Comment: I cannot follow your link. Can you include more background? Under this output convention it seems computable functions are not composable, so I doubt this was Cooper's intention.

Comment: Does the (first) link work better know? Or didn't you mean it technically? (The background is Cooper's convention. And he explicitly aims at composing computable functions.)

Comment: Thanks, now the link works.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the situation in the following way. Add two new symbols to mark the leftmost and rightmost ends of the work tape that you've ever been through. Given a Turing machine, it's easy to construct another one which maintains these symbols and otherwise behaves the same. Now it's easy to gather the 1's since you only have to look for them in this finite marked range.

Comment: Thank you, Yuval. But this implies that there are no "free" pure 2-symbol Turing machines (that allow to follow this convention), right? (By the way: one new symbol would suffice, wouldn't it?)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case, though it's not a proof.

Comment: But the proof would not be hard, would it?

Comment: It's not clear even how to formulate the claim, so it's hard to say whether the proof will be easy or hard.